# Accessing SMS messages on SIM

Tags: android, sms, sim-card

I need to access SMS messages stored on the SIM (NOT on the phone).

According to grepcode ( http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/telephony/SmsManager.java ), the android telephony.SmsManger API includes a public function "getAllMessagesFromIcc()" and indicates this existed from 2.1, however the official android SDK supports no such function.

Why the discrepancy?

This function would do precisely what I need. If it does not exist, how can I read an SMS message currently on the SIM?

I did find this post on stackoverflow ( [Retrieving the SMS Messages from the SIM card on with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126903/retrieving-the-sms-messages-from-the-sim-card-on-with-android) ), which SEEMS to do what I want, but it in fact extends "Broadcast Receiver", which I interpret as catching incoming messages, not reading messages already stored on the SIM.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what do you do if the user doesn't have a sim?

Comment: Use of this application where the user has no SIM is an exception case. The application will indicate an error.

Comment: Okay, just FYI, there are a huge number of users that don't have sims, but you probably know this

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.
There are a number of public functions in Android that are marked with an "(@HIDE)" tag. These functions are stripped from the android SDK to discourage (well, pretty much prevent) their use by the average programmer.

Of course, the challenge introduced is just too much for *some* programmers...

For more info, see:
http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Unfortunately, it seems like current phones (a Samsung Galaxy S, and a LG, 2012) have removed the file he refers to, so the above process is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

This has been one thing I have been battling with myself. It is true that a lot of functions were marked with the @HIDE annotation.

After some period of research, I noticed I could take advantage of the hidden method for reading SIM messages using Reflection. You can look up Reflection in Java.

**Please note** that in using hidden/internal methods, you are not guaranteed that these methods would exist or have same behavior across the existing android platforms (versions).

Import the below packages

```
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```

Below is a sample code to try, it worked for me anyway.

```
public ArrayList<SmsMessage> getSimCardMessages() {

    // this implementation was recorded to work for android 1.6
    // it was tested Ok on android 2.3

    ArrayList<SmsMessage> list = new ArrayList<SmsMessage>();

    try {
        Class<?> smsMgrClass = Class.forName("android.telephony.SmsManager");
        Method getSMSMgr = smsMgrClass.getMethod("getDefault");
        Object smsDefaultInstance = getSMSMgr.invoke(null);
        Method getMessages = smsMgrClass.getMethod("getAllMessagesFromIcc");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        list = (ArrayList<SmsMessage>) getMessages.invoke(smsDefaultInstance);

        Log.d("sms manager", "length: " + list.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

You might want to look up http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/telephony/SmsManager.java#SmsManager.getAllMessagesFromIcc%28%29 for details on the used android inbuilt class and method invoked in the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access a serial device (Android [seems to have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16404344/23118) `/dev/smd0` available), then you can read SMS messages from the SIM with the following AT commands:

```
AT+CPMS="SM","SM"
AT+CMGF=0
AT+CMGL=4
```

The above is PDU mode, use the following for text mode

```
AT+CPMS="SM","SM"
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CMGL="ALL"
```