# Using AT commands with an Android phone

Tags: android, shell, at-command

I'm writing a program that is able to send and receive data from the GSM modem in my Android phone with AT commands.

I execute the following shell script:

```
su
echo -e "AT+CSQ?\r" > /dev/smd0
cat /dev/smd0 > /dev/asd.txt
```

The asd.txt file is created, however there is nothing in it (it should write out the signal strength). It looks like it hangs at the cat command, I think because it doesn't get any output. I've tried some other commands, but I had no luck so far. Can you recommend anything?

Comment: 'cat' is generally not a reliable tool to read from a serial port - you might need to make your own.  But your real problem is that the Android platform code which manages the modem is probably consuming the response before you can.  Trying to go behind it's back is probably not a good idea.  Finally, the above will not literally work as 'su' does not result in sticky rootness - you need to execute the following commands in the root shell resulting from the su invocation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program, it should behave like the following:

```
$ echo AT+CSQ | atinout - /dev/smd0 -
AT+CSQ
+CSQ: <rssi>,<ber>

OK
$
```

Run as `... - /dev/smd0 /dev/asd.txt` if you want to capture the results like in your code.
Notice that you should run `AT+CSQ`, not `AT+CSQ?`.

(the Makefile in atinout-0.9.tar.gz needs a small change to compile, the git source is fine).

Comment: can you briefly describe that what changes i've to do in makefile?

Comment: You need to compile it with a suitable [cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), which I believe available through android's [NDK tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_NDK), but I have never done this myself so my knowledge stops here.

Comment: how tu use atinout in android? @hlovdal